# Error message on gated checkin

Tags: tfs

I've got TFS 2010 running with gated check-in. I've got two TFS servers. Let call one as BaseLibraryWorkspace and the other ClientLibraryWorkspace.  While checking-in changes to a  solution which is on BaseLibraryWorkspace I get the message

`"There is no working folder mapping for $/ClientLibrary/LocalTestSettings.testsettings"`.

The BaseLibraryWorkspace does not refer to anything from the ClientBaseLibraryWorkspace, but it still keeps failing my builds. What to do?

Comment: "While checking-in changes to a solution which is on BaseLibraryWorkspace" please explain what you mean by this

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have your builds definitions setup like this:

```
Build =   BaseLibraryWorkspace 
Mapping =   /$BaseLibraryWorkspace/
Build =   ClientLibraryWorkspace
Mapping =   /$ClientLibraryWorkspace/
```

Now if you create a shelveset with the some files like so:

```
/$BaseLibraryWorkspace/File1.cs
/$ClientLibraryWorkspace/File2.cs
```

And check it into the **BaseLibraryWorkspace** it will try to unshelve it into a workspace on the build server.

The workspace on the server only knows about items under the path **$/BaseLibraryWorkspace/** so when it tries to unshelve **/$ClientLibraryWorkspace/File2.cs** it doesn't know what to do with it. It only knows about **$/BaseLibraryWorkspace/**.

Now this is only a warning, and not an error and the whole shelveset is checked in after a gated build so your files will be up to date.

To fix the issue, you either have to setup the Workspace Mapping on the build to `$/` or only build shelvesets for builds that match the build servers' workspace mappings.